# How to handle deadlocks while multiple batch inserts?

Tags: postgresql, insert, transaction, deadlock, bulk-insert

I need suggestions/ideas of handling a issue with deadlocks.
I'm having multiple batch inserts commands to same table:

```
insert into ip (id, p_id, m_type, m_id, sha256, path) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,$7,$8), ($9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16), ($17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24), ($25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31 ,$32), ($33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38,$39,540), ($41, $42, $43,$44,545, $46, $47,$48) ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

And since Insertion order is not honored in database most probably because PostgreSQL is launching several parallel insert threads, I'm getting the following deadlocks:

```
[1111]:ERROR:deadlock detected 
[1111]:DETAIL: Process 1111 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1423145219; blocked by process 2222.
Process 1111 waits for ShareLock on transaction 1423145222: blocked by process 1111.
Process 1111: insert into ip (id, p_id, m_type, m_id, sha256, path) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,$7,$8), ($9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16), ($17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24), ($25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31 ,$32), ($33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38,$39,540), ($41, $42, $43,$44,545, $46, $47,$48) ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
Process 2222: insert into ip (id, p_id, m_type, m_id, sha256, path) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,$7,$8), ($9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16), ($17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24), ($25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31 ,$32), ($33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38,$39,540), ($41, $42, $43,$44,545, $46, $47,$48) ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

As we can see the bulk inserts acquire ShareLocks which deadlock each other.

On the one hand I don't want to acquire an exclusive lock for each bulk insert on the entire table because I guess it will affect the parallel inserts performance.

On the other hand I'm not 100% sure that enforcing order (by id column which is a PK with a CTE select) is a good solution, because even if I could guarantee insertion order that would NOT ensure a later select statement would return them in that order since it's multiple bulk insertions, and the order might change.

(And also I have to reorder the table for each bulk insert).

Comment: What does 'a later select statement' have to do with your current predicament?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to make sure that no two of the concurrent statements try to insert rows with the same primary or unique key. And no, `ON CONFLICT` doesn't do that trick.

The second best solution is to sort the rows inserted by a single statement before inserting them:

```
WITH r (id, p_id, m_type, m_id, sha256, path) AS
(
   VALUES
      ($1, $2,  $3,  $4,  $5,  $6,  $7,  $8),
      ($9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16),
      ...
)
INSERT INTO ip (id, p_id, m_type, m_id, sha256, path)
SELECT * FROM r
ORDER BY r.id;
```

That should only cause live locks, but no deadlocks.

Of course there are other causes for deadlocks like triggers, but you didn't mention any such details.